# Compare character variable to a series of values in R

Tags: r, comparison

I am new to R from SAS hence please excuse any incorrect usage of R terminology.

I am trying to compare a character variable to a series of values in an IF statement and I am unable to find the correct operator that is equivalent to 'IN' in SAS or SQL.

Here is the code snippet

```
for (i in 1:nrow(step5)) {
if  (step5$CLASS[i]==c("A","B","C","D") step5$class_new[i] = step5$CLASS[i]
}
```

Comment: You want the `%in%` function, ... NOT "==". You also need to search out answers on vectorization. (This question has been asked many times before in SO.) The if() function will NOT be efficient. Read `?ifelse`, `?'if'`, `?'%in%'`

Comment: My apologies, I guess I did not know the right term to use for searching.Thanks for the pointer and response

Comment: I completely understand the difficulties in searching when the terminology is new. Learning the specific names for R data structures is difficult.